# Why is tsconfig.json baseUrl being ignored in react native app?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I created a new react app with `npx react-native init testApp --version 0.71.12` then modified/created the following files in my project.

###### ./tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"],
      "tests": ["tests/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["src/screens/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

###### ./babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
          '@screens/*': './src/screens/*',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

###### ./App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import WelcomeScreen from '@screens/WelcomeScreen';

function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <WelcomeScreen />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

###### ./src/Screens/WelcomeScreen.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

export default () => <Text>Hello, world</Text>;
```

When I run this app with `yarn ios`, this results in the following error, where the path `@screens/WelcomeScreen` is invalid.

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module @screens/WelcomeScreen from /Users/user/Projects/testapp/App.tsx: @screens/WelcomeScreen could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
```

Autocompletion in VS Code works fine which is really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to run

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```